# Defined color scheme and legend categories

Tags: r, colors, legend, categories

Can anybody tell me how to break the legend categories to defined categories? and also the defined colors to each category. I need to define 5 categories in the legend (0-15, 15-30,...etc) and also defined color for each category.

I am using the R code below.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
  county_choropleth(final, num_colors = 1) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")[ceiling((0 : 60) / 10)], 
                       breaks = pretty(final$value, n = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Could this previous answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33113398/5065588

Comment: This is helpful but is there a way I can categorize the range of values and assign a color for each category of values in that range. For example, 0-10 (red), 10-20 (blue) etc.

Comment: You could use something like this: 'c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black')[ceiling((1 : 50) / 10)]', but then replace 1 : 50 with the values you are trying to plot. The division by 10 is because I assume your range is 1:50. Color choice was totally random.

Comment: Thanks. But, please see my code above and image. Since I have negative values my range is from -60 to + 60. So, how can I break this range to 5 categories like -40 - -30 (red) likewise and assign colors to each category.

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear. The range goes from -60 to 60 and you want to make 5 ranges?

Comment: 5 or 6 it does not matter to me. I want to categorize the values into ranges and assign color to it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution inferred from your request is to discretize your values into five classes ranging from the minimum to the maximum value. Discretization can be done with the function `cut`. You'd then pass the breaks and the labels that you want your factors to have. I created some labels pasting together the values of the breaks because then the `county_choropleth` will use those exact same values for the legend. Note that since I create a new `data.frame` all your original data remains unchanged, in case you'd like to double check

```
nBreaks <- 5 + 1
breaks <- seq(min(final$value), max(final$value), length.out = nBreaks)
intBreaks <- round(breaks)
labels <- paste(intBreaks[1:nBreaks-1], intBreaks[(1+1):nBreaks], sep = ':')
newFinal <- data.frame(value = cut(final$value, 
breaks = breaks, labels = labels), 
region = final$region)
county_choropleth(newFinal, num_colors = 5)
```

This solution is a bit of hack, but it would give you five colours for the five intervals. Adjusting the breaks of `cut`, which are now defined as a evenly spaced sequence, will give you more customization powers. HTH

Comment: Thanks. Where can i insert this in the code.? Can you show me where to include this in my code above?

Comment: You can download the data (final) I used in my code using this link. https://bft.usu.edu/p38jv

Comment: Ok. I did as you suggested but the output is still the same.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, that was more a toy example for you to try to get the values in the correct range. I updated the answer now with a solution which I think is more suitable for your needs

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. Now, how can I assign color for each category of values.?